# Ubuntu Screen command does not recognize Lumen Queue command

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, laravel-5, lumen-5.2

I am in a bit of a situation where I need to manually restart queues on linux/ubuntu based box and the proper approach I was told to follow is to use the screen command line application.

I am on Ubuntu 14.X and when I do an `-ls` command I can actually see the sessions running on the server. Below is a command I would run if I was outside screen session:

```
mycommandline$ php artisan queue:restart
```

Now the issue is that if from the `-ls` output I grab the session's port to include in the command I run I get the error below:

> Cannot exec 'php artisan queue': No such file or directory

I also tried typing `screen "php artisan queue:restart"` and I keep getting the same issue.

I am not farmiliar at all with the screen program and any suggestions to point me to the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: you need to fullpath to artisan

Comment: first you have to go your project directory (Ex:- cd  D:/www/myproject) then try to run artisan command

Comment: @Farkie I have just tried that by locating the alias I am using and if I test the full path on the command line itself it is working but if I do `screen "php   /path/to/artisan" I get same message pinting to the full path and then one that says "[screen is terminating]". @SarangaR I already can do that and it  is what I have been doing but I was advised to rather interact with the system through the screen session application for whatever reason my boss knows.

Answer (score 1):

Okay digging through google I came up with the command below. Given that I already had a session that was running I needed to make sure that I send my commands on that same session just to be sure. Below is what I ended up doing which does confirm that something is happenning within the screen session:

```
luyanda@devbox:~$ screen -d -r 19167 -p0 -x stuff "free -g; php artisan queue:restart"
Attaching from inside of screen?
```

As I am not seeing any visible issues I am convinced that this is what I needed to do given that my log file is updating as well it either means that the queues never stopped working or I managed to restart them.

What I am still interested to know is how I can actually see the output of the commands I send to my session else if I can rather pipe the output somewhere else.

Any thoughts?